# Access to service API on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

How to get services endpoints on Kubernetes cluster, the services are type:

- ClusterIP.

Is there another way from port forwarding?

I want to create some API tests but the port forwarding is closing after a few minutes and I should restart it often which is not good.

Comment: Can you use service type `NodePort`?

Comment: i am not admin of the cluster i cannot change thy type of the service

Comment: @Alexa it is not role of cluster admin to to change application deployment.

Comment: @rkosegi so i should change the service type and then i will able to reach via IP.is it correct? Can you give me an example because i am not super specialist in kubernetes?

Answer (score 1):

you can use **node-port** for a testing scenario or else if you can't do it

you can : **kubectl proxy** or `kubectl port-forward svc/<service name> <Port number>`

if your port forwarding getting closed in 5 min you can increase the time.

you can specify the `streaming-connection-idle-timeout`. E.g. `--streaming-connection-idle-timeout=1h` to set it **1** hour.

however, still, **port-forwarding** is mainly for debugging short term issues, for long periods use **node-port** only using which you can connect directly.

Example yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: MyApp
  ports:
      # By default and for convenience, the `targetPort` is set to the same value as the `port` field.
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      # Optional field
      # By default and for convenience, the Kubernetes control plane will allocate a port from a range (default: 30000-32767)
      nodePort: 30007
```

you can update the service name as per need.

Comment: how node-port can be used can you give me an example

Comment: you can run `kubectl patch svc <YOUR service name> --type='json' -p '[{"op":"replace","path":"/spec/type","value":"NodePort"}]'
`

Comment: just changing the service to `NodePort` will probably not work and will need to change the port that is exposed on the node as well.